# When dynamically loading a class in java

Tags: java, class, jvm, classloader

Suppose in java I'm dynamically loading class `A`.
Class `A` uses both java standard library classes and
user defined classes.
I'm wondering what is the classloader that has to load all of the classes used by `A` ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the the way you have designed the classloader that loaded the class `A`

First of all, the classloaders will have a hierarchical relation among them.

**Standard Java mechanism (Parent first):**

Usually when you have to load a class, by default, it follows this pattern:

1. Check if the parent classloader can load the class (each class loader will delegate to its parent)
2. If the parent cannot load the class, then the child class loader attempts to load it.
3. If the child is also not able to load it, then a ClassNotFoundException is raised.

**Special Case (Child First):**

In this scenario, the child class loader (that is your class loader can attempt to load the class), if this class loader cannot load the required class, then it can ask the parent to load the class. If the parent cannot load the class, then a ClassNotFoundException is raised

In any scenario, the java core classes should be loaded by the parent class loader.
However in theory, you can always make your custom classloader to load those classes as long as you have access to the jar containing those classes